# Setting Environment Variables in S2I

Tags: s2i

Currently I am attempting to set an environment variable from my S2I assemble file like so

`export VARIABLE=some_dynamic_value`

When I actually run the container built by my builder, the environment variable does not exist. Is there a way for the builder to set environment variables dynamically?

Comment: does the env present on the built image's metadata?

Comment: @NKR Not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can put it in the `.s2i/environment` file. Like described here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_online/3/html/using_images/source-to-image-s2i#dot-net-core-configuration

Comment: Would be nicer if you provide a small example then provide the link for more details.